# Can I use information from a field to be part of a hyperlink field in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a table that has a field named Employee ID.  Each employee has his/her own folder in the computer.  At the database, I have a "Folder" field as hyperlink that when it is clicked it should open the folder for that particular employee.

Im looking for a way to store a standard path in the field "Folder" (example: C:\Users\Default\Desktop) and add the Employee ID to the end of the hyperlink so it automatically updates the field and opens that specific employee folder. (example: "C:\Users\Default\Desktop\" & [Master].[Employee ID])

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your *Folder* field was created as Hyperlink datatype, you can use a Before Change [data macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx) to load the values you need.

[image: Before Change Data Macro design]

Be sure to include the `#` characters at the start and end of the path string to get a usable link:

```
"#C:\Users\Default\Desktop\" & [Employee ID] & "#"
```

Comment: I did as suggested, but the fields remain blank.  The "Folder" field was created as Hyperlink datatype, and I included the "#" when creating the data macro.  I even set the value to "#C:\Users\Default\Desktop\#" to see if it worked but not a single record gets updated, not even when I click on them.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I started deleting information so I could send you a test and it started working.  Maybe another field in another table was conflicting with the command or it was simply the fact that I closed and opened the database again.